# How to append store code in home page

Tags: magento2.3

WE are using magento 2.3.3 p1 EE version to one of our site.Url doesn't contain the store code before we switch the store code.
How to display the home page URL with store code

Comment: Could anyone give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

it is in the configuration, check the image above, hope that helps

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I did to append the storecode.
Problem is that if i access my homepage for the first time the url will be without store code. But URL should contain the store code. I've tried to put rewrite rules in htaccess but without success, i've tried planty of possibilities. If I witch the stores store code will be appended to the url.